How changed of range date in Magento 2 to /customer/account/edit/
I'm experiencing an issue with the date input field in the customer edit section. The year range is currently limited, and I need to expand it. Could someone please advise on how to increase or extend the year date range for this field?


in layout
app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_edit.xml
<head>
    <script src="Vendor_Module::js/my-custom.js"/>
</head>

write the script js in my-custom.js in app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js
    require([
    "jquery", 
    "mage/calendar"
], function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $("#fecha_de_nacimiento").calendar({
        showsTime: false,
        dateFormat: "dd/MM/y",
        buttonText: "Seleccionar Fecha",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "1940:+0",
        showOn: "both",
    });
});

happy Codding!
